# Sign Up and Sign In not working

Tags: android

i am doing android app development and working on login module now i am trying to sign up and in case username already exists it shows a message that username already exists and user should sign in.

My Code
//sign up

```
    public void addButtonClicked(View view) {
    LogIn ln = new LogIn(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

    dbHandler.addUser(ln);
    printDatabase();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    boolean r = dbHandler.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(username.getText().toString());
    if (r) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

//for sign in ,after sign in it should move to next activity but its not working

```
public void buttonClicked() {
    boolean h = dbHandler.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(username.getText().toString());
    if (h) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), third.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

//db handler code

```
        public  boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String fieldValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_LOGIN + " where " +   COLUMN_USERNAME + " = " + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            cursor.close();

            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Login Class details

```
public class LogIn {
private int _id;
private String _username;
private String _password;

public LogIn(){
}

public LogIn(String username,String password){
    this._username = username;
    this._password = password;

}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}


public void set_password(String _password) {
    this._password = _password;
}

public int get_id() {

    return _id;
}

public String get_username() {
    return _username;
}

public String get_password() {
    return _password;
}

public void set_username(String _username) {

    this._username = _username;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide LogIn Class details.

Comment: You add a user to the DB, then check if it's there and wonder why it is there?

Comment: What does "its not working" actually mean?

Comment: @Henry what i want is if a user sign up i want to store his/her details in database.and if that user already exists he/she just need to sign in and move to next page or next activity.in my case none of them is working.

Comment: do you have any errors, crashes, logcat exceptions?

Comment: also logic in `addButtonClicked()` i think it's not correct, as you should first check if exist, then if NOT, you insert a new record, else you show that toast.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to suggest/correct the areas i think it's causing an issue,
posting your logcat or any errors will help more...

1- the logic of addButton:

you should check if user already exist, and act based on this
currently you are inserting a record and then check if it's exist,
hence `r` will always be `true` !

change the method as below:

```
public void addButtonClicked(View view) {

    boolean r = dbHandler.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(username.getText().toString());
    if (r) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }else{
        LogIn ln = new LogIn(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

        dbHandler.addUser(ln);
        printDatabase();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

2- I think you have an error in the sql-query at method `CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot()`
**though i think you should use** [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

**A.** fixing current code: you are missing single quates wrapping the value (as it's string) `where userName='Smith'`

```
public  boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_LOGIN + " where " +   COLUMN_USERNAME + " = '" + fieldValue + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        cursor.close();

        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

**B.** use `query()`:

```
public  boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String fieldValue) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LOGIN, null, COLUMN_USERNAME+"=?", new String[]{fieldValue}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually there are no errors or exceptions when code is run but when i click the one of the sign in or sign up button it shows the application has stopped working .i have noticed it is due to if statement i am using.is there any other solution possible?

Comment: when you get that message (app has stopped) there must be an exception and the exception has a `stackTrace` this stackTrace can be found in logcat, you need to get it here, so we can find out what is the problem, other than that it will be hard to guess...